# Cast Object[] to MyType[] fails

Tags: java, android

I receive JSON from http server and i know what type it is, but I prefer to receive it as Object (just to keep it generic for code reuse), here is my code to cast arrays:

```
   public static <T> T[] convertArray(Object[] array, Class<T[]> desiredTypeClass) {
    try {
        return desiredTypeClass.cast(array);

    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Also I tried like:

```
MyDesiredObjType[] array = (MyType[]) objArray;
```

I get the same error exception:

> W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast [Ljava.lang.Object; to [Ldata.model.MerchantObj;
>           at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:2432)

When try to cast `Object[]` to `MyType[]`

Comment: What is the link between`MyDesiredObjectType` and `MyType`?

Comment: @AxelH oh, sorry, they're the same, just edited

Comment: Can you show what is your test case ? I am able to make this works to convert an `Integer[]` store in a `Objec[]` typed variable using `convertArray(array, Integer[].class);`

Answer (score 0):

You should copy directly object by object.

```
System.arraycopy
```

Should be the best solution for you.
Please see this document for **arraycopy**

[System class document by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)